Module not found: Can't resolve 'ipfs-http-client' in 'C:\Users\omkar\OneDrive\Desktop\Major Project\Land-Registry-Application\src'
I’ve installed the ipfs-http-client module using npm and it’s also in my node_modules.
When I ctrl+click it also redirects.
But when I run “npm start”
Module not found: Can't resolve 'ipfs-http-client' in 'C:\Users\omkar\OneDrive\Desktop\Major Project\Land-Registry-Application\src'
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
I’ve tried deleting node_modules, clearing cache and again npm install but still gives the same error.
